# Ruby skipping weekends and holidays

Tags: ruby, loops, datetime, activesupport

Here I am trying to skip predefined holidays in an array, but the loop in infinite.

```
@holidays = [DateTime.new(2016,03,15), DateTime.new(2016,03,17)]

def skip_holidays(date)
    date += 1
    while @holidays.map{ |holiday| holiday == date} do
        date = date.next_day.change(hour: 9)
    end
    date
end

skip_holidays(DateTime.new(2016,3,14))
```

However, this loop here works perfectly

```
def skip_weekends(date)
  date += 1
  while (date.saturday?) || (date.sunday?) do
    date = date.next_day.change(hour: 9)
  end   
  date
end

skip_weekends(DateTime.new(2016,3,14))
```

How is that and how to go around it?

Comment: The @holiday.map output an array. [false,true] is considered as true. Even [fasle,false] will be evaluated as a true condition. Try using @holidays.include? instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
@holidays = [DateTime.new(2016,03,15), DateTime.new(2016,03,17)]
def skip_holidays(date)
    if @holidays.include?(date)
        date = date.next_day.change(hour: 9)
    else
        date += 1
    end
end
skip_holidays(DateTime.new(2016,3,14))
```

Comment: Perfect! However, the loop won't work if you change the date of second holiday from 17 to 16! Any suggestions?

Comment: I would do simple if and else not run the look here. It is not need.